# Why does it make sense that $n=\infty$ for a polytropic process gives us a constant volume process?

Tags: thermodynamics

Read that for a polytropic process $PV^n=k$, that "n=infinity" (i.e $n \to \infty$) represents a constant volume process.

The argument given is if you take the nth root of both sides, you still have a constant on the right. Now if you take the limit, $P^{1/n} \to 1$ and so you have $V=k$

However, you could make a similar argument by dividing both sides of the equation by $V^n$ ($V^n \neq 0$) and now if you take $n \to \infty$ you get $P=0$. A constant pressure process where pressure stays zero. Physically, this is probably meaningless, but I want to know why this is wrong and the above is right.

Besides, V=k doesn't seem to be a sufficient condition to make the equation true. Say you take V = 5. The left hand side will tend towards infinity, not a constant. So even on a mathematical level I'm confused why these two ways of solving for the limit are giving different answers.

Comment: Perhaps this explains it: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytropic_process#/media/File:Polytropic.gif
Note also that $\lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}V^n$ depends on the units of $V$: ($2^\infty=\infty$, but $0.5^\infty=0$.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Physically, what this process equation for large $n$ tells us that the volume increase is very small compared to pressure decrease during the process and vice-versa. Differentiating the process equation,we get
$nPV^{n-1}dV+V^ndP = 0$ which can be rewritten as
$\frac{dV}{V} = \frac{-1}{n}\frac{dP}{P}$. So, fractional change in V is $\frac{-1}{n}$ times the fractional change in $P$ with process parameter $n$.
So, for process with higher $n$, fractional change in volume is much smaller compared to fractional change in pressure. It becomes negligible for high $n$. Hence, we say that process can assumed to constant volume process.

Now, lets understand the gaps in your argument. Mathematically, when you take limit with respect to $n$, you are assuming $k$ to be a constant but that is not true because process constant itself varies with $n$ (dimensions of $k$ scale with dimensions of $V^n$). For large $n$, $k$ would also be large for process happening in similar pressure and volume states. So, $P$ does not tend to 0 as $n$ tends to $\infty$ because $k$ increases in similar proportions as $V$.

One more example like this is seen in semiconductor physics where diode current increases exponentially with forward voltage. So, assumption we generally take while solving circuit equations is that voltage across the diode is a constant.

Comment: Okay, so the equation really is: $PV^n = k(n)$

Comment: Yes, the dimensions of $k$ should match the dimensions of $PV^n$. But the major point over here is that value of $k$ is not important to understand the fractional change because we have transformed the equation to non-dimensional values in which $k$ disappears.

Comment: No I'm not talking about the dimensions. I mean is it fair to say k is a function of n

Comment: Definitely, yes. But the reason behind it is again dimensionality. Suppose $k$ is same for  for more than one $n$ for some choice of units of $P$ and $V$. Then, consider we rewrite the equation where units of $V$ and $P$ are halved. Then, the value of $k$ would scale differently for different $n$ ( $k_{new}(n)$ becomes $k^{n+1}$) . So, we get dependence of $k$ on $n$. Since choice of units is arbirtary, in general, its good to write dimensionless form of equations to see relationship between different physical quantities.

Comment: There is a typo in my previous comment. $k_{new}$ becomes $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}} k$.